# Multiple values one field mysql

Tags: mysql

Basically I have a a mysql database which i want to create containing the following tables:

- artist
- song
- album

A song can belong to only one artist, however, a song could be in Multiple Albums. How would I go about implementing this in my mysql database. I've been stuck for a few days now :(

Comment: What have you tried so far? Have you created some tables? What columns did they have?

Answer (score 4):

You're looking for a [join table](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Join_Table):

```
albumsong
    album       -> FOREIGN KEY to album
    song        -> FOREIGN KEY to song
    tracknumber
```

Then join to query:

```
SELECT song.*, albumsong.tracknumber
FROM albumsong
JOIN song ON song.id=albumsong.song
WHERE albumsong.album=(some album id)
ORDER BY tracknumber;
```

Since some albums are collaborations, you might also have a many-to-many relationship for artists/albums, too:

```
artistalbum
    artist      -> FOREIGN KEY to artist
    album       -> FOREIGN KEY to album
```

Answer (score 2):

You would use an intersection table.  For example:

Artists:

- Artist ID (Primary Key)
- Artist Name

Song:

- Song ID (Primary Key)
- Artist ID (Foreign Key)
- Song Name

Album:

- Album ID (Primary Key)
- Album Name

AlbumSongs

- AlbumID (Foreign Key)
- SongID (Foreign Key)